# Socket-io connection errors with https server

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io, cors

I've got myself a typescript project consisting of a NodeJS (express) backend and a ReactJS frontend, that communicate via socket-io. Initially, both of them were running over http (http://localhost:3000 for the frontend and http://localhost:5000 for the backend).
Now I tried switching them both to https (this is required for my project) and while that worked fine with React, I since then failed to build the socket-io connection between them. Here are some more infos:

- Everything worked fine with http, but since the backend was set to https, the problems occured
- The backend cannot keep using http, because browsers would block mixed contents
- Firefox outputs "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:5000/socket.io/?userId=undefined&EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Ot7wQRj. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)"
- Chrome outputs: "net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

This made me think about a problem with my ssl certificates. I created these myself using:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

My server does this:

```js
    'use strict';
    import https from 'https';
    import { Server } from 'socket.io';
    import express from 'express';
    import cors from 'cors';
    import serverConfiguration from './util/ServerConfiguration';
    import Controller from "./Controller";
    import * as fs from "fs";
    
    // setup server
    const app = express();
    app.use(cors());

    const credentials: https.ServerOptions = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/sslcert/key.pem', 'utf8'), // files are loaded correctly
        cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/sslcert/cert.pem', 'utf8'),
    };
    
    const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
    const io = new Server(httpsServer, {
        cors: {
            origin: `https://localhost:3000`,
        },
    }).listen(5000);
    io.on('connect', () => console.log('do something'));
```

And this is the socket-io code from my client:

```js
    import {io, Socket} from 'socket.io-client';
    
    const socket = io("https://localhost:5000", {
        query: {username: "foo"},
    });
    socket.on('connect', () => console.log("do something"));
```

I have also tried calling the backend server from the commandline: `curl https://localjost:5000 --insecure -vvv` and got

```
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (5454) (IN), , Unknown (72):
* error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
```

while calling the http url seems to be returning a 404 status.

Does anyone have an idea, what I can do about these error messages? I have already tried setting `rejectUnauthorized: false` on the client as well as the server (nothing changed) and all kind of other tips I found online, but so far nothing worked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update:
It seems like the combination of express and socketio outputs a http response. If i replace all socketio code on the server with static responses, the server is working fine. But i still dont know why socketio has a problem with these requests

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might stumble upon this problem: I did'nt get it to fix it the way I intended. But I was able to make it work by removing the express server and only relying on socketio and websockets. I connected with the url `ws://localhost:5000` and changed my server code to:

```js
'use strict';
import {Server} from 'socket.io';
import serverConfiguration from './util/ServerConfiguration';

const BACKEND_PORT: number = serverConfiguration.API_HTTP_PORT; // 5000
const FRONTEND_PORT: number = serverConfiguration.REACT_HTTP_PORT; // 3000
const FRONTEND_DOMAIN: string = serverConfiguration.REACT_APP_DOMAIN; // https://localhost

const io = new Server(BACKEND_PORT, {
    cors: {
        origin: `${FRONTEND_DOMAIN}:${FRONTEND_PORT}`,
    },
});

io.on('connect', () => {/*...*/});
```